# bitronix transaction manager

Tags: spring, jta

I'm trying to migrate from JPA to JTA and use bitronix transaction manager. I'm getting below error message when try to run unit tests. According to bitronix documentation this is normal b/c my spring context configuration is trying to load the resources twice (once in base class and then in the test class, see code below), I have tried the same with atomikos and I got similar result.

> Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   resource with uniqueName 'xyzDb'
>   has already been registered

My base class

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:com/xyz/baseContext.xml"})
@Transactional
public abstract class AbstractTestSupport extends Assert implements ApplicationContextAware
{
```

In some unit tests I have to extend the test support and add a context config file like below. so it loads context once for base class and another time for child class and fails

Child class

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:com/xyz/testContext.xml"})
public class UnitTest extends AbstractTestSupport
{
```

After the test I'm shutting down context, so next test works fine as long as it doesn't extend the base class with another context config file.

```
@AfterClass
public static void onTearDownAfterClass() throws Exception
{
    applicationContext.shutdownApplicationContext();
    assertFalse("Spring application context is still active after shutdown. ", applicationContext.isActive());
}
```

I want to keep context config files in the child classes and make this work like that, any ideas greatly appreciated....

Comment: What is in the two XML files?

Comment: just an off-topic note: i had a bad impression of bitronix tm and even some tests showing it performs worse than jboss standalone transaction manager when it comes to features like transaction suspending.

Answer (score 1):

The error message basically means you created the connection pool with unique name 'xyzDb' (remember there is a uniqueName property you need to set on BTM's pools?) for the second time at the time the exception is thrown. You cannot do that: each connection pool must have a unique name and must be closed before another one with an identical name can be created.

I suppose there is some overlap between your two context files causing this or maybe the connections pools aren't always closed like they should. Unfortunately you published too little information to get a definitive answer.